# Reducer changed state but does not re render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Here is my reducer:

```
export interface RootState {
  todos: ToDo[];
}

const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

export const todo = (
  state: RootState = initialState,
  action: Action
): RootState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TODO_ADD:
      return {
        todos: [...state.todos, action.payload.todo]
      };
    case TODO_TOGGLE_COMPLETE:
      let todoArr = [...state.todos];
      todoArr.forEach((todo: ToDo, index: number) => {
        if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
          todoArr[index].isComplete = !todo.isComplete;
        }
      });
      return {
        todos: todoArr
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action:

```
export const TODO_ADD = "TODO_ADD";
export const TODO_TOGGLE_COMPLETE = "TODO_TOGGLE_COMPLETE";

export interface Action {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
}

export interface ToDo {
  id: string;
  todo: string;
  isComplete: boolean;
}

const add = (todo: ToDo): Action => ({
  type: TODO_ADD,
  payload: { todo }
});

export const toggleComplete = (id: string): Action => ({
  type: TODO_TOGGLE_COMPLETE,
  payload: { id }
});

export const addToDo = (todo: ToDo) => (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch(add(todo));
};
```

and my component to call toggle complete:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Row, Col } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ToDo, toggleComplete } from "src/actions/todo";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  toggleComplete: (id: string) => dispatch(toggleComplete(id))
});

type MapDispatchToProps = ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>;

type Props = MapDispatchToProps & {
  todo: ToDo;
};

class TodoItem extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { todo } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Col span={20}>
          <h3>{todo.todo}</h3>
        </Col>
        <Col span={4}>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.props.toggleComplete(this.props.todo.id)}
          >
            {todo.isComplete ? "Completed" : "Complete"}
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const Container = styled(Row)`
  width: 100%;
`;

export default connect<undefined, MapDispatchToProps>(
  undefined,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem);
```

`todo` is getting from component list

```
import * as React from "react";
import { List } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "src/reducers/todo";
import { ToDo } from "src/actions/todo";

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  todos: state.todos
});

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;

class TodoList extends React.Component<StateProps> {
  render() {
    const { todos } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <List
          header={
            <div>
              <h2>Todo List</h2>
              <h4>
                There are {todos.length} {todos.length === 1 ? "todo" : "todos"}
              </h4>
            </div>
          }
          bordered
          dataSource={todos}
          renderItem={(todo: ToDo) => (
            <List.Item>
              <TodoItem todo={todo} />
            </List.Item>
          )}
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
`;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList);
```

I already implemented subscribe here:

```
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
```

and see the state changed, but component not re render.

Comment: you aren't passing mapStateToProps in your connect call. change `undefined` to a function and pass the store data to your component... aka something like `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ ...state.todos })`

Comment: as a side note you dont actually need to mapDispatch, connect passes dispatch to the component. You could just dispatch directly from there. That way you dont need to add a function to the dispatch map each time you want to add one :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell, sr check my update, from `ToDoItem` I get `todo` from component list outside

Comment: ok, are you combining the reducers somewhere? have you inspected the prop values in the `TodoList` component where you are mapping state to props?

Comment: Just one reducer, not combined. And TodoList mapping is correct, I added item and it showed that item, but when I change the field `isComplete`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnRuddell if you want whole project, I can send you :)

Comment: That would be helpful haha, I was going to set up a fiddle and copy paste a lot  lol

Comment: write down your email or some thing here, I will send it to you

Comment: sent, please check :)

Comment: Fixed it, let me know if you have more issues :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is how you are mutating state in your reducer. Change line 24 in your reducer file from this

```
todoArr[index].isComplete = !todo.isComplete;
```

to this

```
todoArr[index] = {...todo, isComplete: !todo.isComplete};
```

essentially what you were trying to do is mutate a state object directly instead of creating a new object signature.

Another issue you are going to have is currently you're creating new todos with the same id. So all items are marked as completed  when you complete one. Instead of this, you can just use the current timestamp as a unique id.

Change this

```
const todo: ToDo = {
  id: "1",
  todo: value,
  isComplete: false
};
this.props.addToDo(todo);
```

to this

```
const todo: ToDo = {
  id: `${new Date().valueOf()}`,
  todo: value,
  isComplete: false
};
this.props.addToDo(todo);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks @John Ruddell :)

Comment: @Khuong anytime! Let me know if you need more help :)